# У заминусованного сообщения не осветляются ссылки действий

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Когда пост заминусован, он и комментарии осветляются до наведения мышки. Логично, что ссылки тоже надо, а то они сейчас ярче всего остального. Проявляется как на мете, так и на основном сайте.

[image: скриншот меты]

[image: скриншот ruSO]

Comment: По-моему, они и так достаточно тусклые.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, но они ярче самого поста...